# Failed to enhance data nucleus

Tags: android, google-app-engine, gradle, datanucleus

After updating my gradle to 1.0.1, my appengine build fails

I get the error:

`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'enhancerApi' on com.google.appengine.AppEnginePluginExtension_Decorated@1dd443c1`

It looks like `enhacerApi` has been deprecated but I'm not sure how to solve this.

> App Engine SDK root = C:\Users\steve.gradle\appengine-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.17
>   Java classpath = C:\workspace\ShoutBox\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar;C:\Users\steve.gradle\appengine-sdk\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.17\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar
>   Webapp source directory = C:\workspace\ShoutBox\appengine\src\main\webapp
>   Enhancing DataNucleus classes...
>   Finished enhancing DataNucleus classes.
>   :appengine:appengineEnhance FAILED
>   :appengine:appengineEnhance (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 1.043 secs.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':appengine:appengineEnhance'.
>
>   > An error occurred enhancing DataNucleus classes.
> - Try:
>     Run with --debug option to get more log output.
> - Exception is:
>     org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':appengine:appengineEnhance'.
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
>         at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
>         at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
>         at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
>     Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: An error occurred enhancing DataNucleus classes.
>         at com.google.appengine.task.EnhanceTask.enhanceClasses(EnhanceTask.groovy:58)
>         at com.google.appengine.task.EnhanceTask.executeTask(EnhanceTask.groovy:34)
>         at com.google.appengine.task.AbstractTask.start(AbstractTask.groovy:38)
>         at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
>         ... 47 more
>     Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'enhancerApi' on com.google.appengine.AppEnginePluginExtension_Decorated@1dd443c1.
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.propertyMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:35)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.getProperty(CompositeDynamicObject.java:94)
>         at com.google.appengine.AppEnginePluginExtension_Decorated.getProperty(Unknown Source)
>         at com.google.appengine.AppEnginePlugin$_configureEnhance_closure9_closure58.doCall(AppEnginePlugin.groovy:313)
>         at com.google.appengine.AppEnginePlugin$_configureEnhance_closure9_closure58.doCall(AppEnginePlugin.groovy)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper$2.getValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:84)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper$MappedPropertyImpl.getValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:136)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper.getConventionValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:114)
>         at com.google.appengine.task.EnhanceTask_Decorated.getEnhancerApi(Unknown Source)
>         at com.google.appengine.task.EnhanceTask$_enhanceClasses_closure1.doCall(EnhanceTask.groovy:52)
>         at com.google.appengine.task.EnhanceTask$_enhanceClasses_closure1.doCall(EnhanceTask.groovy)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(BasicAntBuilder.java:92)
>         at com.google.appengine.task.EnhanceTask.enhanceClasses(EnhanceTask.groovy:42)
>         ... 57 more
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 19.158 secs
>   Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the missing api tag in gradle build file solves the issue

```
enhancer {
    version = "v2"
    api="jdo"  // or "jpa"
    enhanceOnBuild = true
}
```